# A "row ID" é igual à chave primária?

Tags: android, sqlite, chave-primária

A função [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) do Android retorna uma `row ID` segundo a documentação,

> the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

A `row ID` corresponde à chave primária, `ID`, se existir?

Comment: É uma chave única, mas não a primária. Por ventura o `id` acaba sendo atualizado, mesmo que o dado em si seja o mesmo. Quando ocorre? `INSERT OR REPLACE`, o `id` acaba sendo trocado após essa operação

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em algumas situações, sim.

> The PRIMARY KEY of a rowid table (if there is one) is usually not the true primary key for the table, in the sense that it is not the unique key used by the underlying B-tree storage engine. The exception to this rule is when the rowid table declares an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. In the exception, the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY becomes an alias for the rowid.

[Fonte](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html).

> A chave PRIMÁRIA de uma tabela rowid (se houver uma) geralmente não é a chave primária verdadeira para a tabela, na medida em que não é a chave exclusiva usada pelo mecanismo de armazenamento B-tree subjacente. A exceção a esta regra é quando a tabela rowid declara uma INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. Na exceção, a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY se torna um alias para o rowid.

Portanto sua modelagem poderá fazer isso ser verdadeiro ou não. O que é recomendado fazer assim na maioria das vezes.

[Útil também](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).